# Are there any coding standards that need to be followed before minifying a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, minify

I have a set of JavaScript files in my project. I want to minify them. I want to know how minifying happens & are there any coding standards that should be followed while minifying the source code?

Comment: Unlike most "coding standards" questions, this is a question of whether coding standards have real effects on the behavior of a minifier. This question is not at all opinion-based (unless you consider the implementation of a minifier to be the "opinion" of its author or something). It may well be too broad, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minifier that transforms valid javascript into invalid javascript is a buggy minifier. No special care is necessary, although following best practises can improve the minification results as those patterns is what the minifier will be looking for (depending on how sophisticated it is).

Comment: "following best practises can improve the minification". What are those best practises?

Comment: @Sunil Babu: Depends on the minifier. You'll probably need to find this out for yourself based on what you're using or plan to use.

Comment: After minifying some of the functions are not working, that is why i asked any standards are there.

Comment: @SunilBabu: Standard javascript best practises, as documented around everywhere (style guides, tutorials etc). Just don't use any weird patterns.

Comment: @SunilBabu: If you are having a specific problem, you should ask a specific question, including the minifier you're using, the setup, the input code and the output code. Best [post a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Thanks  BoltClock .